# Comparable compareTo function

Tags: java, string, comparable, compareto

I'm trying to have a Comparable function compareTo two street addresses. I'm working on the String (street name) of the address at the moment. So far, I have the following code. I eventually want to be able to compare the street numbers too, but I'd like to be able to get this code fixed first. Whenever I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
StreetAddress.java:45: error: constructor StreetAddress in class StreetAddress cannot be applied to given types;
    StreetAddress add1 = new StreetAddress("cartesian road");
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
StreetAddress.java:46: error: constructor StreetAddress in class StreetAddress cannot be applied to given types;
    StreetAddress add2 = new StreetAddress("cartesian road");
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
StreetAddress.java:47: error: constructor StreetAddress in class StreetAddress cannot be applied to given types;
    StreetAddress add3 = new StreetAddress("n kings street");
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
StreetAddress.java:48: error: constructor StreetAddress in class StreetAddress cannot be applied to given types;
    StreetAddress add4 = new StreetAddress("pioneer parkway");
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
StreetAddress.java:49: error: constructor StreetAddress in class StreetAddress cannot be applied to given types;
    StreetAddress add5 = new StreetAddress("starry avenue");
                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
5 errors
```

---

```
public class StreetAddress implements Comparable<StreetAddress>
{
protected int num;
protected String stName;

public void StreetAddress(int n, String s){
num = n;
stName = s;
}

public int getNum(){
    // returns the street number
    return num;
}

public String getName(){
    // returns the street name
    return stName;
}

public int compareTo(StreetAddress street) throws ClassCastException{
    // exception prevents crash if an address is not compared to
    // another address
    StreetAddress x = (StreetAddress) street;
    int compareName = this.stName.compareTo(street.stName); 
    if (compareName < 0){
        // first address comes after compared address
        System.out.println("test<0");
    }

    else if (compareName == 0){
        // same address
        System.out.println("test equal");
    }

    else{
        // first address comes before compared address
        System.out.println("test > 0");
    }

    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
StreetAddress add1 = new StreetAddress("cartesian road");
StreetAddress add2 = new StreetAddress("cartesian road");
StreetAddress add3 = new StreetAddress("n kings street");
StreetAddress add4 = new StreetAddress("pioneer parkway");
StreetAddress add5 = new StreetAddress("starry avenue");
add1.compareTo(add2);
add4.compareTo(add1);
add3.compareTo(add3);
add2.compareTo(add5);
}
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to subtract one String from another?

Comment: A valid constructor in Java **MUST have no return type**. In your code: `public void StreetAddress(int n, String s)` - this is not a valid constructor. It should be: `public StreetAdress(int n, String s)`

Comment: @informatik01 That fixed all of the issues I was having. I came up with a few other errors, but I was able to fix those. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not edit your question to insert your solution. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to let people search for problems and their solutions; So your question should remain the question/problem you had, the the answers below indicate possible solutions to try. I have reverted your post for you. Thanks!

Comment: `// exception prevents crash` No it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, as you note, is with:

```
compareName == this.stName - (street.stName);
```

You can't subtract strings. The way to get the result I think you're looking for is:

```
int result = this.stName.compareTo(street.stName);
```

Obviously this assumes that `stName` is a `String`. If not you will have to implement `compareTo` within the class that `stName` is, as I see you have done in an edit. The issue you report with your edit is that the class is as follows:

```
class StreetName {
    // Constructor
    StreetName(int n, String st) {
         // code
    }
}
```

However, you are trying to instantiat the class as follows:

```
StreetName fred = new StreetName("name");
```

You are only sending the constructor a `String`, and not an `int` with it. Assuming the number is important, you need to change that to:

```
StreetName fred = new StreetName(number, "name");
```

Comment: After using this syntax, I now receive 5 errors in the main class which I have reposted.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to subtract one String from another? That doesn't quite make sense. Instead how about calling String's own `compareTo(...)` method at that spot. Plus the `==` operator shouldn't be there:

```
int compareName = stName.compareTo(street.stName);
```

Also, your compareTo method is defined to return an int, and so it had better return that int. Right now it is not returning anything.

Comment: After changing both the compareName to string, and using the compareTo function, I still get the same error.

Comment: @AmpageGrietu: are you still using `==` and not `=`? One is for equivalence which is not what you want, and the latter is for assignment which is what you want. Show your code as an edit to your original question please.

Comment: No I have changed it to the single = operator.

Comment: @AmpageGrietu: then again, edit your original post and add the new code to the bottom with any error message you are now receiving.